# Works on repl.it doesn’t work no freeCodeCamp - JavaScript Algorithms and Data Structures Projects: Roman Numeral Converter

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

just finished my Roman Numeral Converter, and it works fine on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@gonunex/Roman-Numeral-Converter) , but on the [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/roman-numeral-converter) the output is:

```
// running tests
convertToRoman(2) should return "II".
convertToRoman(3) should return "III".
...
// tests completed
```

check my code please, on repl.it it work fines. It can convert arabic numbers to roman numbers:

```
let arr = [];
function splitNumber(num) {
  let len = num.toString().length; //get length of the number
  let d = Math.pow(10, len);


  for (let i = 0; i < len + 1; i++) {
    const x = num % d; // remainder from num to d save number by unit, decimal, etc..
    if (d > 1) { 
        d /= 10;
        arr.push(Math.floor(x / d) * d); // save the value in the array
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

function convertToRoman(num) {
  splitNumber(num);
  let arabicToRoman= {
   1: 'I',
   4: 'IV',
   5: 'V',
   9: 'IX',
   10: 'X',
   40: 'XL',
   50: 'L',
   90: 'XC',
   100: 'C',
   400: 'CD',
   500: 'D',
   900: 'CM',
   1000: 'M'
 };
 let array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let a = arr[i]
    if (a > 1 && a < 4) {
      array.push(arabicToRoman[1].repeat(a));
    } else if (a > 5 && a < 9) {
      array.push(arabicToRoman[5],arabicToRoman[1].repeat(a - 5));
    } else if (a > 10 && a < 40) {
      array.push(arabicToRoman[10].repeat(a / 10));
    } else if (a > 50 && a < 90) {
      array.push(arabicToRoman[50],arabicToRoman[10].repeat(a / 10 - 5));
    } else if (a > 100 && a < 400) {
      array.push(arabicToRoman[100].repeat(a / 100));
    } else if (a > 500 && a < 900) {
      array.push(arabicToRoman[500],arabicToRoman[100].repeat(a / 100 - 5));
    } else if (a > 1000) {
      array.push(arabicToRoman[1000],arabicToRoman[1000].repeat(a / 1000));
    } else {
      array.push(arabicToRoman[a]);
    };
  };
  num = array.toString().replace(/,/g,'')
  return(num);
};

convertToRoman(36); // number 36 as an example, you can change it
```

help would be great to understand what am I missing with freeCodeCamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertToRoman(num) {

  let roman={
    1:"I",
    4:"IV",
    5:"V",
    9:"IX",
    10:"X",
    40:"XL",
    50:"L",
    90:"XC",
    100:"C",
    400:"CD",
    500:"D",
    900:"CM",
    1000:"M"
  }
  
  function roManify(num,i){
    let roNum;
    if (num==0){
      roNum = "";
    }
    if (num>0&&num<4){
      roNum = roman[i].repeat(num);
    }
    else if (num==4){
      roNum = roman[num*i];
    }
    else if(num>4&&num<9){
      roNum = roman[5*i] + roman[i].repeat(num-5);
    }
    else if(num==9){
      roNum = roman[num*i];
    }
    return roNum;
  }

   num = String(num).split("");

   if (num.length == 4){
     let result;
     result = roManify(num[0],1000)+roManify(num[1],100)+ roManify(num[2],10)+roManify(num[3],1);
     console.log(result);
     return result;
   }
   else if (num.length == 3){
     let result;
     result = roManify(num[0],100)+roManify(num[1],10)+ roManify(num[2],1);
     console.log(result);
     return result;
   }
   else if (num.length == 2){
     let result;
     result = roManify(num[0],10)+ roManify(num[1],1);
     console.log(result);
     return result;
   }
   else if (num.length == 1){
     let result;
     result = roManify(num[0],1);
     console.log(result);
     return result;
   }
  
}

convertToRoman(3999);
```